# СМЭВ 3, SMEV 3. Взаимодействие с сервисом через СМЭВ путем выкладывания видов сведений через FTP и отправкой их получателю

Tags: c#

Добавляю ссылку на сервис http://esb.smev.vpn:10180/serviceSmev3Prod/Smev3Prod?wsdl
Формируются классы для взаимодействия. Получается сразу не работающее приложение.
При вызове метода client.SendRequest получаем следующие ошибки.

Невозможно создать временный класс (результат=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentType' to 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentList'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentType' to 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentList'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentList' to 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentType'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentList' to 'SMEV3Services.SMEV3.AttachmentContentType'

Пример Кода 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пришлось руками править автоматически сформированный код, чтобы получилось взаимодействовать с СМЭВ 3.
Подскажите как сделать чтобы при добавлении ссылки на этот сервис классы формировались правильно?
Сервис СМЭВ 3 написан на JAVA.

Comment: Вы бы хоть код привели, не у всех же доступ к этой VPN есть. А вообще, ситуация очень странная: не должно быть ошибок в автогенерированном коде, где-то вы что-то не так сделали.

Comment: И да, при чём тут вообще FTP?

Comment: При том что не правильно формируются классы именно для того сервиса у которого в взаимодействии прописано выкладывание файлов на FTP. Если бы ошибок не было то я бы не писал, Если вы не сталкивались с таким проблемами, то зачем вообще писать не разобравшись? Чтобы показать что вы очень умны? В итоге не ответив по теме. Вы говорите:  Что то делаете не так. Ну а как сделать так? Есть ссылка на wsdl. Добавляем её в проект. Проблема не только была у меня по этому я и решил спросить кто как решал подобные проблемы. Если у вас нет опыта работы в СМЭВ, то не нужно умничать и спамить. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот как раз опыт работы со СМЭВ у меня есть. А с вашей проблемой я при этом не сталкивался. Значит, вы что-то не так сделали. А вот что вы сделали не так - я сказать не могу, потому что вы ничего не рассказали.

Comment: Давайте тогда продолжим, на каком языке программирования вы взаимодействуете через СМЭВ? C#? Просто не понятно как мне избежать не правильного формирования классов на основе wsdl ? И если у вас есть опыт взаимодействия то почему у вас нет доступа к wsld по адресу http://esb.smev.vpn:10180/serviceSmev3Prod/Smev3Prod  ???? Просто это основа взаимодействия с СМЭВ как бы..... или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @PavelMayorov при добавлении в .NET ссылок на сервисы, разработанные на Java такое бывает, что сгенерированный код надо дорабатывать напильником. Со СМЭВ не работал, но для другого API у меня была похожая ситуация, приходилось менять руками `Foo[][]` на `Foo[]`, чтобы все заработало. (Не знаю, на чьей именно стороне баг.)

Comment: Я это гуглил, по этой причине и выложил пример своего приложения. И пример Foo[][] заменить на Foo[] не применим в этом примере. Очень хорошо что вы сейчас загуглили, что встречаются данные проблемы. Но получается что ваши коментарии как и оценка моей теме является не объективной так как вы по этому вопросу не можете помогать не имея опыта решения этого вопроса.

Comment: @holyfortesque вы сюда пришли за решением проблемы или чтобы объяснить что я не могу вам помогать? Если первое - то где, собственно, проблемный код? (тот, что привели вы, никак не может привести к указанным вами ошибкам компиляции!)

Comment: Это проблема не компиляции, а runtime при сериализации.

Answer (score 3):

Проведя не мало часов получилось вот такое решение проблемы.
Проект с работающим кодом для взаимодействия с одним из сервисов выложенных в СМЭВ 3
https://gitlab.com/Projects_v.a.andiev/example-smev3
Переписал руками автосформированный код. 
Темы которые будут полезны для разработки сервисов СМЭВ 3
https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=12094&p=2
https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=8840&p=6

Если не хочется смотреть проект.
То подправил такие места

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге можно дальше работать с СМЭВ и отправлять, получать сообщения от СМЭВ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]